# XOR value in JQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have a small script where I need one value to xor. Someone pointed out how to do it, but I have since changed the script and his suggestion doesn't apply here anymore.

```
<input type='button' value='Ein / Aus' class='taster' csv='Lampe' />        

<script>            
    $(document).on('click', 'input.taster', function() {

        // Get ID from Input
        var id = $(this).attr('csv');

        $.get('plc.php?function=csv&id=' + id, function(data){
            var csv = data.split(',');

            //Output
            var out = csv[1];

            //Write
            var wdatatyp = csv[2];
            var wdb = csv[3];
            var wbyte = csv[4];
            var wbit = csv[5];      
            var bitval = csv[6];

            //Read
            var rdatatyp = csv[7];
            var rdb = csv[8];
            var rbyte = csv[9];
            var rbit = csv[10];

            $(document).load('plc.php?function=write-bit', {'wdatatype':wdatatyp, 'wdb':wdb, 'wbyte':wbyte, 'wbit':wbit, 'bitval':bitval}); 

            function read() {               
                $(out).load('plc.php?function=read-bit', {'rdatatype':rdatatyp, 'rdb':rdb, 'rbyte':rbyte, 'rbit':rbit});                    
            }
            setTimeout(read, 100);                  
        });             
    });         
</script>
```

A little cleanup and better description of what needs to happen.

csv[6] is fetched from the csv file and will always return 1.

So what I need is the first time the script is called, bitval needs to return a 1. The next time it needs to return a 0, then a 1, then a 0, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `bitval` to an `int` before XORing it. So replace the line

```
var bitval = csv[6];
```

with

```
var bitval = parseInt(csv[6]);
```

The toggling can be then done this way (by moving the bitval declaration out of the onClick handler):

```
var bitval = null; // this is crucial since you don't have another place to store the value
$(document).on('click', 'input.taster', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('csv');
    $.get('plc.php?function=csv&id=' + id, function(data){
        // your variables
        if (bitval == null) { // initial set
            bitval = parseInt(csv[6]); // was 'var bitval = csv[6]'
        }
        // your load code
        bitval ^= 1; // toggle
    });
});
```

Comment: and then how would I go about XORing it? I'm not entirely sure how to do it since I'm not parsing that value from an input.

Comment: You just change the one line. Your XORing will work.

Comment: But `$(this).attr('bit-val', bitval^1);` can't work. Since there is no more 'bit-val'.

Comment: Then what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Hmm I've tried all mentioned solutions here but none seem to work. My goal is that the first time the script is run bitval will return 1, the next time it is called it has to return 0, then 1 again, and so on.

Comment: You need to move the `bitval` declaration out of the click handler, see my updated post.

Comment: Does the suggested solution `var bitval = Number(csv[6]) ^ 1;` from rink.attendant.6 work for you?

Comment: unfortunately no, bitval will always return 0 now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52417/discussion-between-artjom-b-and-bavilo)

Answer (score 0):

As Artjom mentioned, you need to convert it to a number since [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns strings.

```
var bitval = Number(csv[6]);
```

You can do the [XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)ing in the same step:

```
var bitval = Number(csv[6]) ^ 1;
```

In the case that the value cannot be converted to a number, the Number function will return `NaN` (not-a-number). `NaN ^ 1` equals 1. If that result is undesirable, you can do a type check:

```
var bitval = Number(csv[6]);
if (isNaN(bitval)) {
    bitval = ...;
}
```